# copy paste from rubymine to terminal not working

Tags: ubuntu, rubymine

When I trying copy-paste from `rubymine` to terminal its not working.
But working when it paste in notepad,browser others.

Using `Ctrl+Shift+C/V` does not work.

problem with copying from Netbeans to terminal. It seems that when you `Ctrl+C` in Netbeans, it isn't copied in pure text format, so you can't paste it in terminal which require that kind of format (this is an assumption based on my experience ;) ).

So, how do I do it? Just copy from Netbeans, then paste it in some text editior, on example gedit, then copy it again and just paste in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using`shift + insert` or middle mouse button after selecting the text.